# universal reference as parameter and return type

Tags: c++11, c++14, move-semantics

**Universal references as parameter or return type**

I read a few articles about universal references but I still don't understand in which cases I might need to use this as a parameter type besides the move constructor. Could someone enlighten me?

```
void Foo(Bar&& x);
Bar&& Foo();
```

Under which circumstances would I ever want to have this which I couldn't solve with a simple `Bar&` to move something?

**When to use std::move**

Could someone explain me when an explicit `std::move` is necessary (for parameters and return types) under which circumstances I can expect that the compiler uses it automatically during the optimization phase? For example

```
struct A { A(A&& src) ... };

A Foo()
{
    A a;
    ...
    return a;
}
```

In this case I might benefit from RVO, so should I even ever consider using std::move for a result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Universal reference is when the type is deduced. You don't deduce the type, `Bar&&` is just an r-value reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Universal references

The example you've provided doesn't actually use universal references, those are just r-value references. Syntactically, the universal reference is an r-value reference to a parameter of a deduce templated type:

```
template <typename Bar>
void foo(Bar &&bar);
```

This is actually different then a regular r-value reference and it is used to solve a [perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward) problem. But I assume this isn't what your question is about.

## R-value references

In most cases when you want to move the value to or from the function you can simply do it by value:

```
void foo(Bar b);
...
Bar somebar;
foo(std::move(somebar)); //function argument is move-constructed

/**************************************************************/

Bar foo()
{
    Bar somebar;
    return somebar; //return value is move-constructed
}
```

Doing this using l-value reference is actually incorrect:

```
void foo(Bar &b)
{
    Bar somebar = std::move(b); //you "stole" passed value
}
...
Bar somebar;
foo(somebar); //but the caller didn't intend to move his value
```

Also returning **any reference** to a local variable is wrong.

The only reason one would use r-value reference instead of passing by value is to **allow moving** the value without actually moving it one extra time:

```
Bar &&Foo::foo()
{
    return memberBar;
}
...
Foo f;
Bar b = f.foo(); //"b" will be move-constructed
...
f.foo().doBar(); //returned "Bar" value is just used and not moved at all
```

## When to use `std::move`

You need to use `std::move` every time you want to move a variable **even if it's already an r-value reference**:

```
Foo::Foo(Bar &&bar)
    : memberBar(std::move(bar)) //still need to move explicitly!
{
}
```

You **don't** need to use `std::move` when:

- Returning a local variable by value
- Passing a temporary to a function, e.g. `foo(Bar())`
- Passing non-movable types (those without move-constructor) including primitive types

A common mistake:

```
Bar *bar = new Bar();
foo(std::move(bar)); //not needed! nothing to move since the pointer is passed and not the object itself
```

**However** when using a conditional operator:

```
Bar foo()
{
    Bar somebar;
    Bar otherbar;
    return std::move(true ? somebar : otherbar); //need to move explicitly!
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thanks